# CSS not displaying inline on first page load

Tags: html, render, css

My page renders incorrectly (not how I want) on the first load, then when refreshed is correct. It's has to do with the "display:inline-block" I think. I've done a lot of research but I can't seem to figure this one out. And yes.... I've cleared my cache before loading it, I get the same result.

first load:
[image]

after refresh:
[image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
    <body>

        <div id="header">
            <div id="ribbon-start"></div>
            <div id="ribbon-shade"></div>
            <div id="banner">   
                <div id="titles">
                    <div id="name">The Person</div>
                    <div id="profession">Their Profession</div>
                </div>
                <div class="tip"></div>
                <div class="nav-butts">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- header -->

        <div style="height:900px; width:1px"></div><!-- SCROLL TEST -->

        <div id="footer">
            <div id="toTop">^</div>
        </div> <!-- footer -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryeasing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sticky.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/behaviour.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
body{
background-color:#00FFFF;
}
#ribbon-start{
z-index:-2;
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:0px;
width:49px;
height:100px;
background-color:#181818 ;
}
#ribbon-shade{
z-index:-1;
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:25px;
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 11px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
border-right:24px solid  #909090   ; 
}
#banner{

margin:21px 0 0 17px;
width:90%;
height:100px;
background-color:black ;
-webkit-box-shadow: -6px -4px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    -6px -4px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
box-shadow:         -6px -4px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
#titles{
    display:inline-block;
}
#name{
margin: 0 0 0 80px;
font-size:84px;
font-family: 'RalewayLight', sans-serif;
color: white;
display:inline-block;
}
#profession{
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
font-size:34px;
font-family: 'RalewayLight', sans-serif;
color: white;
display:inline-block;
}
#banner .tip{
display:inline-block;
margin: 0 -49px 0 0;
float:right;
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
border-left: 50px solid black;
}
.nav{
margin:0 0 0 17px;
width:90%;
height:100px;
}
.nav-butts{
display:inline-block;
padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;
background-color:black;
border-radius:38px;
margin:8px 0 0 0;
float:right;

}
.circle{
margin:5px 8px 0 8px;
display:inline-block;
height:60px;
width:60px;
background-color:white;
border-radius:30px;
}
.sticky {  
margin-top:10px;
position: fixed;    
left:-8px;
top:-8px;  
z-index: 100;  
border-top: 0;  
} 
.sticky .nav-butts{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px -2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px -2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px -2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
#toTop{
position:fixed;
text-align:center;
left:10%;
bottom:-15px;
height:60px;
width:70px;
font-size:64px;
background-color:black;
font-family: 'RalewayThin', sans-serif;
color: white;
border-radius:20px;
cursor:pointer;
}
@font-face
{
font-family: RalewayBold;
src: url('fonts/Raleway-Bold.otf');
}
@font-face
{
font-family: RalewayLight;
src: url('fonts/Raleway-light.otf');
}
```

Comment: Does any of those js plugins have anything to do with your element?

Comment: yes, but I've disabled them and I still get the bug

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me on the first load. I have worked with php in the past and found that an error appears underneath at the first load but disappears at the second load. Try different browsers. One may just be acting up.

Comment: try pasting the URL into another tab and load again, I almost guarantee it will not load correctly... it's very inconsistent (hence my confusion).

-also i have tried FireFox Chrome and Safari, all the same

Comment: I tried doing as you recommended, and the result was all skewed like you explained. I know that it is not a fix, but you could always insert an automatic refresh into the html. Then the user will never see the messed up page. Even if you use it as a temporary fix until you figure out the real problem.

Comment: Though that would work, I don't want to spam the server with requests. I'm just incredibly curious as to what is behind this bug.

Comment: Also, there's not really a simple way to do that without the page refreshing infinitely.

Comment: I see your points about the refreshing. I'll play around with html/css a bit and see what I can figure out. I'm not sure if I'll figure out what's wrong, but I'll try nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I've included this line

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

This clears the problem but isn't really the answer to this question. This code makes the browser call for the styles instead of using cached ones for every load, I believe.